# Can android:buttonStyle and android:imageButtonStyle be used for Theme.MaterialComponents?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, android-imagebutton

For Theme.AppCompat, one can use `android:buttonStyle` and `android:imageButtonStyle` to style `Button` and `ImageButton` respectively for all activities. They do not seem to work for `Theme.MaterialComponents`. If not, what is the equivalent for `Theme.MaterialComponents`?
Could anyone shed some light on this?

The old theme example:

```
<style name="OnviferThemeStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
     ...   

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/fooButton</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/fooButton</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/fooImageButton</item>
    <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/fooImageButton</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the MaterialComponents theme you can use the **`materialButtonStyle`** attribute.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/....</item>
</style>
```

For the `ImageButton` currently there isn't a Material Components. You can still use the `ImageButton` component and the `imageButtonStyle` attribute.